# Fast fourier transform went wrong

Tags: javascript, opencv, image-processing, fft

I tried to implement FFT using this code: [Rosetta Code FFT](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#JavaScript)

Here's a screenshot of the result I got:
[FFT gone wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmVt1.png)

Here's my code where I used the above FFT on an image:

```
function fastFourier(img){

let height=img.rows;
let width=img.cols;
let tmp=createArray(height,width);
let temp=createArray(height,width);
let rows=createArray(height,width);
let prettypls=img.clone();

//new complex array
for(i=0;i<height;i++){
  for(j=0;j<width;j++){
  rows[i][j]=new Complex(0, 0);
    }
}

//put pixel values in complex array
if(height%2==0&&width%2==0){
  for ( y = 0; y < height; y++) {
    for ( x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    let pixel = img.ucharPtr(y,x);
    rows[y][x].re=pixel[0];
  }
}

//perform fft
for(y=0;y<height;y++){
  tmp[y]=cfft(rows[y]);
}

//take the magnitudes
for(i=0;i<height;i++){
  for(j=0;j<width;j++){
    temp[i][j]=Math.round(tmp[i][j].re);
  }
}

//do a log transform
temp=logTransform(temp,height,width);

//put the real values into Mat
for(i=0;i<height;i++){
  for(j=0;j<width;j++){
    let pixel = prettypls.ucharPtr(i,j);
    pixel[0]=Math.round(temp[i][j]);
  }
}
cv.imshow('fourierTransform', prettypls);
rows=[];temp=[];tmp=[];prettypls.delete();
}
else alert('Image size must be a power of 2.');
}
```

I did the log transform based on [this](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/fourier.htm) description of FFT. Here's my log transform code:

```
function logTransform(img,h,w){
//https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/pixlog.htm
let max=findMax2d(img,h,w);
let c=255/(Math.log(1+max));
for(i=0;i<h;i++){
  for(j=0;j<w;j++){
    img[i][j]=c*Math.log(1+Math.abs(img[i][j]));
  }
}
return img;
}
```

I have no idea what I did wrong. The FFT results are fine when it's just a normal array, but using it with images returns the above results.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting exactly what you asked for: for each row in the image, an analysis of the intensity frequencies *in that row*. Your code treats each row as an individual array of samples, and takes the FFT of that.

What you probably want is a two-dimensional FFT as described here: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ia/lect2.pdf

Right now, you are just calculating a series of one-dimensional FFTs, which is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

What [Florian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53515018/7328782) intends to say in his answer is that you need to compute the FFT over the columns of the result you have got.

The 2D DFT is separable. This means that it can be computed by taking the 1D DFT along each row, and then again along each column of the result. Or equivalently, first along columns and then along rows.